# Complete Induction $n\ge2$ is equal to a product of prime numbers.

Tags: induction

Prove by complete induction that any natural number $n\ge2$ is equal to a product of prime numbers.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: Do you mean that *"Every number can be written as a product of prime , which is unique apart from the order"* ?

Comment: Induction has to go downward.  A number $n$  either has factors less than itself but more than 1 or it doesn't.  If it doesn't than it is a prime number.  If it does then those factors are smaller and you use the same argument on them.  And $n$ is finite inductively we "go down" and eventually must end with numbers that can't go further.  Those number have no factors other than themselves or 1 and thus are prime and $n$ is the product of them.

Comment: Prove .........